# Where to store the key for SymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption

We're using the SymmetricAlgorithm in .NET for Encryption. 
The key and provider are configurable through the web.config.

I'm not sure if this is wise, what is the alternative?
we still want to make the provider and key configurable by the end developer.

We have and api ourselves and our consuming developers can call our Encrypt/Decrypt and we then use whatever they have configured in their web.config.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect

Comment: Looks nice but doesn't it do the same thing basically? if used on 2 different machines the key still needs to be stored in a config file!

Comment: But ASP.Net already does that with the `<machineKey>` element.

Comment: I see yes, its still readable is someone gets the physical machines. We currently read the settings from a custom section in the web.config.

Comment: If your enemy has access to the physical machines, you've already lost.

Comment: Big answer for a small question: learn about key management. I'm not sure that that would fit in an answer here. There are many possibities, all with +-es and --es.